# Duplicate symbol error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, duplicates, symbols

I am encountering 'duplicate symbol' errors in Xcode 4.5.1 when I try to build a project after adding my own framework. I verified the framework files for duplicates and there are none. But when I add the framework to a project, it complains with these error. Please suggest..

```
duplicate symbol _NXArgc in:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.3.1.o
/Users/idcc/Test/MyFW/Products/MyTestFW.framework/MyTestFW

duplicate symbol _NXArgv in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.3.1.o
/Users/idcc/Test/MyFW/Products/MyTestFW.framework/MyTestFW

duplicate symbol ___progname in:
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.3.1.o
/Users/idcc/Test/MyFW/Products/MyTestFW.framework/MyTestFW

duplicate symbol _environ in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.3.1.o
/Users/idcc/Test/MyFW/Products/MyTestFW.framework/MyTestFW

duplicate symbol start in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.3.1.o
/Users/idcc/Test/MyFW/Products/MyTestFW.framework/MyTestFW
ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have the same issue, however it does run when i start it on my iPhone. So, i only have this problem in my simulator...

Comment: Same here, only on the simulator...

Comment: I have this specific problem as well.  Looking for an answer, posted a bounty.

Comment: Do you have variables declared in the .m across several files with the same name? I see now that it is giving you the variable names that are duplicated: _NXArgc, start, _environ, _progname, _NXArgv

Comment: those variables are all from the standard libraries... Answer worked swell.

Comment: shows above error while building with simulator but runs successfully with device. No need to follow the below answer , it doesn't solve the matter.

Comment: This can be caused by a number of issues.  One hacky fix depending on your exact problem, is:  in "your" script, replace the "const " in question with "static const ".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those symbols are in crt.o, the startup code of standard C library. Normally it should be the entry point of executable file to initialize global variables and objects. It will also call your main function.

But for a framework, you should not include it in your binary because framework should not have main. 
I believe you have "Link with Standard Library" option as "YES" in your framework's target build setting. This will link crt.o into your framework. And when you link the framework into a project, there will be duplicated symbols.

Please set the option "Link with Standard Library" to NO in your build setting.

Comment: When I set Link with Standard Library to no in build settings, I got 177 compiler errors instead of 1

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue with using two third party framework. I resolved that by removing "all_load" from "Other Linker Flags" in build settings.

Answer (score 8):

Your application has provided an implementation in which there are 8 duplication symbols.

There are a number of ways you might have done this:

You have two modules declaring the same class. Perhaps one is no longer needed?

You are importing any header file in both the files .m and .h :-( Remove from one place.)

You are importing any .m file somewhere. :- (Import .h file instead of .m file)

You have defined and declared any const variable in outside(above) the @interface{} in any of .h file, it might being duplicated. :- (Do it in the .m file.)

Answer (score 2):

Also check, if global variables like constants are defined correctly in `.h` file in application.

The correct way of defining global variable is to use `extern` variable in `.h` file.

Note :This is not an issue with the previous Xcode version. I faced the problem with Xcode 6.3 and it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem only when you run the app in the simulator, it gets solved by deleting the local folder

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
```

Xcode will restore it after the first build and run.
**PLEASE MAKE SURE YOU BACKUP ANY SETTINGS** before doing this (especially those related to simulator devices).

*Tested on Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)*