# Multiple errors arising from IOS build

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile

I am receiving multiple errors when trying to run the flutter build iOS command. I've tried lots of different 'solutions' from GitHub and stack overflow, but nothing has worked yet. `Error output from Xcode build: ↳ objc[57491]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1df053130) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1085ec2c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. objc[57491]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1df053180) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1085ec318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. ** BUILD FAILED **`

I am also getting a duplicate symbol error. Furthermore, I am also getting the following error: `error: linker command failed with exit code 1` . Please let me know if I should attach any other things. I am easily running my code on the android simulators. It is only the IOS ones that are causing me the problems.

Comment: `One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined` is a warning IIRC, shouldn’t be the reason why the build failed

Comment: Should I attach the entire log? I also mentioned that I'm getting a 'duplicate symbol' error and the linker command error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367793/duplicate-symbol-error-in-xcode

Answer (score 4):

run these codes below and then use flutter clean to clean up.

```
cd ios/
  pod cache clean --all
  pod deintegrate --verbose
  pod setup --verbose
  pod install --verbose
```

Comment: Thanks for the commands but unfortunately it didn't work for me.