# Missing file - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang

Tags: ios, ios7

can't exec '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' (No such file or directory)

I get the above error in iOS SDK7 and XCode5.0.1

Hence the system is unable to proceed with compilation. Please help!

Comment: Does `/Applications/Xcode.app` exist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373016/command-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcodedefault-xctoolchain-usr-bi

Comment: OK then, the installation is broken and you should delete it and reinstall Xcode.

Comment: @trojanfoe Will it work?