# All xib and storyboard files crashes Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, uistoryboard

I am having a really difficult problem and have no idea how to fix it. I have a workspace with 3 projects and whatever xib or storyboard file I choose from these, Xcode always crashes, saying (Xcode quit unexpectedly). Also, if I create a brand new project within the workspace, these storyboard also crashes xcode when opening (but project can be built and runs fine, except you cannot open layout files). What could possibly create such an affect? Is the problem in my .xcodeproj file? The project worked yesterday, and I have not performed any change that I can remember.

If I build the project without selecting any xib or storyboard file I receive the following very cryptic error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

Similar to this one: 
[swift failed with exit code 1 while compiling in Xcode - possibly related to Bridging-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889723/swift-failed-with-exit-code-1-while-compiling-in-xcode-possibly-related-to-bri)

Have tested all the answers, on both XCode 6.1 and 6.1.1 (Have tested to delete xcuserdata and DerivedData). If i build using the console, in the end I get this "very" helpful error.

```
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **
```

I guess nobody has a complete solution for this problem, but could you help me on where to look? .xcodeproj file? Or could a error in one xib file prevent others from opening?

Comment: If you started with objc classes then changed to swift is one reason. See Xcode 6 release notes. I got burned by this.

Comment: I do have objc, c and c++ classes which is in a library im using. But I have not changed any objc classes to swift

Comment: Sigh - this is really nasty and I wish I could offer a real solution. I actually had a corrupt disk several months ago - so you could do a Disk Utility verify on your drive. Also, wipe Xcode, download again, and try that. Worse comes to worse, create a new WorkSpace and bring the other projects in one at a time and test. Nasty I know. [Update: looks like a new version of Xcode is out for 8.2.2 beta - could try that release...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was some sort of xCode bug. One of my swift files was corrupt somehow, and the fix was simply deleting it and copying the old content to the new file. Very strange that one SWIFT (!) file could prevent all xib and storyboard files from opening.

My recommendation to anyone having the similar problem is to backup your old project and remove files until xCode works. Then you have identified the problem, and should be able to fix it.