# Xcode 7 beta 5 Error

Tags: ios, macos

Command `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 6`

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: quit your Xcode and restart it

Comment: i have restarted it what else can i do

Comment: most Xcode related problems can be resolved by a quick restart. As it is a beta version, no one had encountered it yet. We need to wait for the next release,if nothing works out.

Comment: i tried to update to beta 5 because the error started in beta 4 and updated and it still did dent work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common problem in the Xcode betas. Check [one of the many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889723/swift-failed-with-exit-code-1-while-compiling-in-xcode-possibly-related-to-bri) other answered questions.