# Command ...swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I am stuck with this error for a while, and none of the solutions I've found seems to work (at least, in my case). Here is the full error log:

```
CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
cd "/Users/user/Documents/Music Kit A"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -target x86_64-apple-macosx10.10 -module-name Music_Kit_A -Onone -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -g -module-cache-path /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -I /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Products/Debug -F /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Products/Debug -c -j4 /Users/user/Documents/Music\ Kit\ A/Music\ Kit\ A/AppDelegate.swift /Users/user/Documents/Music\ Kit\ A/Music\ Kit\ A/main.swift -output-file-map /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Intermediates/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Debug/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Music\ Kit\ A-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Intermediates/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Debug/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Music_Kit_A.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Intermediates/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Debug/Music\ Kit\ A.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Intermediates/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Debug/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Music\ Kit\ A-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Intermediates/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Debug/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Music\ Kit\ A-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Intermediates/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Debug/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Music\ Kit\ A-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Intermediates/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Debug/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Music\ Kit\ A-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Products/Debug/include -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Intermediates/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Debug/Music\ Kit\ A.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Intermediates/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Debug/Music\ Kit\ A.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Music_Kit_A-cimwnaollginmxefzprqiioyrhfl/Build/Intermediates/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Debug/Music\ Kit\ A.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Music_Kit_A-Swift.h

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

What I've tried:

- Clean the project
- Comment my last changes
- Create a new project and transfer the code

When I create a new project, this error goes away, but get another one saying that there is an implicit entry point to `main`. Searched the whole project for a main function, but nothing showed up. My whole code is [here](http://pastebin.com/ckXH5sH0), if it's of any use.

Comment: Post the code that failed also.

Comment: May be the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776445/command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcodedefault-xctoo/26659475#26659475

Comment: @SteveRosenberg I have uploaded my code, the link is in the question.

Comment: @tuoxie007 I've seen that post before asking, but my code doesn't contain any function including the `!` operator.

Comment: Will look it up after work.

Comment: @user26830 please see my answer in that post

Comment: Can't believe it won't give any explanation. My case I found it via viewing at "Show the report navigator", or either @tony508's solution.

Answer (score 9):

Try to use `xcodebuild -project ***.xcodeproj -scheme ***`, it will give you more details about the error.

For me was adding `[unowned self]` to a block inside a block.

Comment: Wish I could +1 this twice.  Nice one!  This should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this code causes the error:

```
processBtn.setTitleColor(.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

But if i add UIColor everything goes fine:

```
processBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

Maybe you have similar errors in you code.

Answer (score 0):

For other people who are having this problem now. Please revert your previously deleted files in the system.

Your project might still be referencing that file somewhere in your project.