# (Swift) Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just working on a project and it is almost completed, the next day I open my project and I started seeing this error

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

I'm using xcode 6.3.2
My project is using many objective C libraries.
Tried all the questions and answers linked below
[Xcode 6.0.1 Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156561/xcode-6-0-1-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcoded)
[GM release of Xcode 6 compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776445/command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcodedefault-xctoo)
[Command /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373016/command-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcodedefault-xctoolchain-usr-bi)
Any idea what else could be the reason?

Edit: As I mentioned in my question that none of them worked for me, please dont down vote it :| I see some smart guy down voted it.

Comment: This is a duplicate question.  If none of the answers in the previous posts worked for you, you should follow up with a comment on the question.

Comment: @JAL are they even active? and none of them are related to swift?

Comment: The first two you linked to are related to Swift: `usr/bin/swiftc`

Comment: well not sure what to do, project is big , just tried to copy to new project. still same error