# How to debug slow Swift compile times

Tags: ios, swift, compilation

I have a Swift SpriteKit project with about 25 smallish files. The time to compile this project is 30-45 seconds! It's pure Swift with no ObjC.

I've watched the compile in the Report Navigator to try to find a single file that's taking the time. But, it's not really a single file. It's always the *last* file in the list that seems to take all the time. But that file can be different between compiles and still takes all the time.

The step right after the last file is Merge xxx.swiftmodule, which happens quickly, but I'm not sure if because it comes right after the slowness it might be related.

I've searched and tried various approaches to find the culprit. I read this post: [Why is Swift compile time so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537614/why-is-swift-compile-time-so-slow) and tried those approaches. I've done a command line build using CTRL-\, but that does not show any useful information about the slowness.

I've gone through my project looking for places where type inference might be getting tripped up, but haven't found much (and really, if that was the case, I'd expect a single file to be the culprit).

Does anyone have any other suggestions for tracking this down? Coming from an Objective-C project that compiles nearly instantly, this is driving me crazy.

EDIT
I worked on this a bit more and am including a screen shot of the build output, noting where the slowness happens. The thing is, if I comment out the code in the slow file, then the file *before* it in the list becomes the slow one (where it was fine before). If I comment that code out, then the one *before* that becomes the slow one, etc.

[image: Build Output]

Comment: Compiling or linking? Without you posting any logs, we can hardly help you, aside from telling you to a) use Swift 2.0, b) wait for Apple to actually release Swift 2.0.

Comment: Type every array and dictionary - don't force the compiler to infer it. I use to type everything - every let and every var - to get compile speed down (on my slow MacBook Air...)

Comment: Thanks Claus. I'll see about grabbing some logs. By the way, I am using Swift 2.0.

Comment: How do you mesure individual file compile times?

Answer (score 6):

After more digging and debugging, I found the problem. It turns out it actually *is* type inference, as other posts have suggested. Part of the problem is that I did not notice that the build output in the Report Navigator shows an arrow for files still compiling and a checkmark for those that are done (my color blindness played a role). So I thought they were all finished compiling when one was not.

In any case, I read the article here: [GM release of Xcode 6 compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776445/gm-release-of-xcode-6-compile/26848000#26848000) and did a command line build of the entire project, which showed me the file that was the issue. Then, using the CTRL-\ approach noted above, I found the culprit.

It turns out that this line was the issue:

```
ourWindowCopy.position = CGPoint(x: ((26.5 + theXOffset) * self.multiplierWidth) + (4.0 * CGFloat(randomRow) * 2.0 * self.multiplierWidth), y: ((41.0 + theYOffset) * self.multiplierHeight) + (5.75 * CGFloat(randomColumn) * 2.0 * self.multiplierHeight))
```

I know it seems a mess - I was playing around with a bunch of different options early on and hadn't yet gone back to simplify. I replaced it with this (and will of course replace the literals as well as simply further):

```
let floatRandomRow = CGFloat(randomRow)
let floatRandomCol = CGFloat(randomColumn)
let pointX: CGFloat = ((26.5 + theXOffset) * self.multiplierWidth) + (4.0 * floatRandomRow * 2.0 * self.multiplierWidth)
let pointY: CGFloat = ((41.0 + theYOffset) * self.multiplierHeight) + (5.75 * floatRandomCol * 2.0 * self.multiplierHeight)

ourWindowCopy.position = CGPoint(x: pointX, y: pointY)
```

Now the compile speed is very fast!

I'm not sure there's really any new information here, but wanted to close this out with a solution in case someone runs across it.

Answer (score 5):

There is a hidden option in Swift compiler that prints out the exact time intervals that compiler takes to compile every single function: `-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies`.

Simple run the following in terminal and analyze results:

```
xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App clean build OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies" | grep [1-9].[0-9]ms | sort -nr > culprits.txt
```

Awesome Brian Irace wrote brilliant article about it [Profiling your Swift compilation times](http://irace.me/swift-profiling).

Answer (score 4):

Building on other answers, the following commands are helpful...

To see a sorted list of functions by build time:

```
xcodebuild -workspace [Your Workspace Name].xcworkspace -scheme [Your Build Scheme Name] clean build OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies" | grep .[0-9]ms | grep -v ^0.[0-9]ms | sort -nr > culprits.txt
```

To see a sorted list of functions that take over 1s to build:

```
xcodebuild -workspace [Your Workspace Name].xcworkspace -scheme [Your Build Scheme Name] clean build OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies" | grep [1-9].[0-9]ms | sort -nr > culprits.txt
```

You can get a list of scheme names like so (this command runs a clean first):

```
xcodebuild -workspace [Your Workspace Name].xcworkspace -list
```

Helpful Articles about why your build times may be long:

- https://medium.com/@RobertGummesson/regarding-swift-build-time-optimizations-fc92cdd91e31
- https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-build-time-optimizations-part-2-37b0a7514cbe
- https://medium.com/compileswift/swift-build-time-reanalysis-optimisations-a875a4168f7a

Comment: If you're using a project (`xcodeproj`) instead of a workspace (`xcworkspace`), then use `-project [Your Project Name].xcodeproj` instead of `-workspace [Your Workspace Name].xcworkspace` in the commands above.

Comment: Instead of the grep/sort part at the end, you can use this command which is updated for the latest output and `zsh`. It removes duplicates, and only outputs those that are 100+ ms: `grep -E '^\d{3,}.\d{2}ms' | sort -nr | uniq -u`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift time compilation**

[Swift Compiler Performance](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/CompilerPerformance.md)

Measure and Tools
You should clean and build your project to have a better results for comparing.

1. Xcode Build time output.

```
//Terminal command
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ShowBuildOperationDuration YES
```

Output:
[image]

2. Build With Timing Summary.

```
//Xcode
Product -> Perform Action -> Build With Timing Summary
```

Output:

```
Report Navigator -> <build> -> Recent
```

[image]

3. Type check warnings

Trigger a warning in Xcode for any function/expressions which is more than a user-defined limit to type-check

```
Build Settings -> Other Swift Flags(OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS)
-Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=200
-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=200
```

Output:

```
Instance method 'foo()' took 200ms to type-check (limit: 200ms)
```

[image]

4. Record a time which is taken to compile every function/expression

```
Build Settings -> Other Swift Flags(OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS)
-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies
-Xfrontend -debug-time-expression-type-checking
```

Output:

```
Report Navigator -> <build> -> Expand All Transcripts
```

`-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies`

[image]

`-Xfrontend -debug-time-expression-type-checking`

[image]

[BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode](https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode) is based on this flag. Also  it has interesting column which is called `Occurrences` - how many times compiler is type checking it(e.g. lazy properties, closures)

[image]

[XCLogParser](https://github.com/MobileNativeFoundation/XCLogParser) analize logs

```
xclogparser parse --project Experiments2 --reporter html --rootOutput "/Users/User/Desktop/temp"
```

[image]

You are able to open Xcodelog with `.xcactivitylog` extension by changing to `.zip` and unzip it. After it you can open it as a text file

```
/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Experiments2-fejelsaznlrfewdtvyfyhhbgxlwl/Logs/Build/00D3B76E-B61B-4FB8-AE0B-1FAD5AF3F452.xcactivitylog
```

[XCMetrics](https://github.com/spotify/XCMetrics)(by Spotify) as a next step of collecting log data

**Notes:**

[`-debug-time-compilation` was removed](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/2198d7174c5857a92e42c5e76e1c1bb9a78db772)

Experiments were made on Xcode v13.3.1. Do not forget to clean project before measure

You are able to set flag for specyfic target(e.g. in modularized project)