# Swift 2 - Xcode 7 - failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, exit

i have this error when i want to build my iOS App in Swift 2 and Xcode 7.0, i tried pretty much everything (clean, rebuild, delete derived date, ..)even re-install xcode but nothing has worked...

> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Thanks!!

RESOLVED:
I re-import all my files and my framework then the issue has disappear.

Comment: Could you provide some code? (i.e. from your project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GM release of Xcode 6 compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776445/gm-release-of-xcode-6-compile)

Comment: Yes of course Arc676 but which kind? The project has a tons of code and i got this error only in xcode 7.1 ... didn't get this error when i was under 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete manually DerivedData folder and restart Xcode

Users/%User%/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: are you using Parse in your project?

Comment: I may know the problem (i had a similar problem), let me search stack overflow for a few minutes and ill get back to you

Comment: probably you mean ENABLE_BITCODE option in project's target Build Settings? You should disable it, since Parse is build without bitcode.
You can try this, but in this case error text should have contain the ENABLE_BITCODE warning

Answer (score 0):

Try Clean and rebuild, also delete derived data too.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete DerivedData folder from window -> projects -> select delete on DerivedData
- Clean Your Project.
- Rebuild

Comment: I tried this but it's not working still the same error .. :/