# Using Xcode 8 while using Xcode 7

Tags: xcode7, swift3, xcode8

I was running Xcode 7 until I upgraded to Xcode 8 which I now have an error code 1.

Error message:

Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Not sure how to fix this error. I have tried cleaning the project but that did not work either.

Comment: See if this helps you [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373016/command-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcodedefault-xctoolchain-usr-bi) or [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156561/xcode-6-0-1-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcoded)