# error: can't exec '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' (Permission denied)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to compile an xCode project that I cloned from Git on an other admin user session of my Mac. I am getting this error

```
error: can't exec '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' (Permission denied)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 71
```

Can anyone can help me through this, thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373016/command-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcodedefault-xctoolchain-usr-bi

Comment: @Brian it didn't help me, I have already seen that before asking my question

Comment: Did you install Xcode from the Mac AppStore?