# XCode build error /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying build an IOS app written in ReactNative. The application written using XCode 11.4. Then I got a new Macbook with XCode version 12.5 installed. So I cloned the project from the git and run npm install and tried to run the project using XCode. Then I got the following error.

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I checked any issues as suggested by the accepted answer in this link,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373016/command-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcodedefault-xctoolchain-usr-bi. But there is nothing wrong with it.

Also, I tried cleaning the project and building the project again. It did not solve the problem as well.

Then I tried deleting the project targets that are for tests well and tried to clean and build the project again. But it did not work either.

I tried deleting everything in the Derived Data folder and tried building the project again as well. It did not work either.

When expand the log, this is the error I am seeing.

```
In file included from /Users/xandasupport/Desktop/Wais/PCL/pcl-app/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi/JSIDynamic.cpp:6:
In file included from /Users/xandasupport/Desktop/Wais/PCL/pcl-app/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi/JSIDynamic.h:8:
/Users/xandasupport/Desktop/Wais/PCL/pcl-app/node_modules/react-native/React/../third-party/folly-2018.10.22.00/folly/dynamic.h:63:10: fatal error: 'boost/operators.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Why am I getting that error and I can I possibly fix it?

Comment: Delete Derived Data and try again

Comment: I tried that too. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share whole message which you can see in the log?

Comment: Try Xcode -> Preferences -> Location -> and in command Line tool select your using Xcode version, clean the project and run

Comment: I just shared the whole message updating the question.

Comment: I cannot use the old XCode version because the app store does not allow the app built using old XCode version anymore. That is why I got the new mac.

Comment: Try to update pod if it not works. Try deintegrate pods and then install again

Comment: When I cd into the ios folder and run pod install it is complaining Podfile not found. Maybe because I am using ReactNative 0.59.x?

Comment: first run "sudo gem install cocoapods" because first time you have to install cocoapods in your system

Comment: I already did that

Comment: This is the problem of cocopods try to reinstall and install them again

Comment: Yes I did that. It is still complaining that there is no Podfile in the directory.

Comment: You have to add previous pod file then to install them

Comment: There was no Podfile at all when I was running the project on previous machine.

Comment: Then how you were using Pods?

Comment: When I run the project, it just worked. I think ReactNative is managing the dependencies?

Comment: Might be possible

Comment: So how can I get it running on the new XCode version?